# Built in Fragment Transitions

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have been trying to test the built in Fragment Transitions located [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) but I do not understand what is going on in the animations (CLOSE, FADE, and OPEN).

More specifically, **what is the animation being used for the built in fragment transaction animations?**  I'm guessing fade is simply cross fading the two, but even when I have tested close and open I cannot figure out what they are doing just by watching them.

I have checked the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/FragmentTransaction.java#FragmentTransaction.0TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE) but cannot find the animation files that are being referenced.

Links and tips for figuring this out are also appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FragmentTransaction` constants you are referring to (`TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN`, etc.) are used in the framework to built in animations.  They vary by the theme in use and what is bundled by the OEM.  For example, the OPEN transaction uses this in AOSP code:

`com.android.internal.R.styleable.FragmentAnimation_fragmentOpenEnterAnimation`

That will map to a specific animation by the OEM.

Answer (score 2):

Check `android-sdk/platforms/android-20/data/res/anim`
Then to use these, set animation as  (e.g) `android.R.anim.fade_in`

Comment: Thanks for showing me these animations, they'll definitely come in handy.  Do you know which are used for built in fragment transaction animations?

Comment: I don't think fragment transactions have a default animation. They just appear (similar to `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`). If you're seeing animations, you're using a specific type of fragment (like say, a DialogFragment), or it's a default set by your OEM's version of android.